# how to grep information from log files distributed in different node machine using Perl

Tags: perl

There are some log files distributed on several node machines /workdir/status*.log , the nodes names are stored in @nodes. 
I need a script on host machine to gather information (eg: grep "information" status*.log ) from each logs and store the result in a file located on host.
Currently I have to scp all the log files manually from every nodes to a host directory and then grep the information. The log file names may be the same in each nodes.
(eg. status42.log exists in both node1 and node2 ...). Is there any better way to do this using Perl?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you may only need a little part of each log files, `grep`ing on remote machines will save lots of network traffic compared to `scp` all those log files wholely to local host and then `grep` them.

You could achieve all those by using modules that allow you to execute commands on remote machines, such as [`Net::OpenSSH`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.60/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm):

```
# UNTESTED script

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;

my @node = (
    'node1@domain1.net',
    'node2@domain2.net',
);

open my $loginfo, '>', '/path/to/loginfo.log' or die "Cannot open file: $!";

foreach my $node (@node) {
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($node);
    $ssh->error and die "Cannot establish SSH connection: " . $ssh->error;
    my @logfile = $ssh->capture('ls /workdir/status*.log');
    $ssh->error and die "Remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;

    foreach my $logfile (@logfile) {
        my ($log) = $ssh->pipe_out("grep information $logfile")
            or die "Remoate command failed: " . $ssh->error;
        while (<$log>) {
            print $loginfo "[$node][$logfile] $_";
        }
        close ($log);
    }
}
```